# How to insert NaT type into MySQL datetime column using executemany

Tags: python, mysql, insert

I have df looks something like this

```
uid | name | txn   | date
 1  |  a   | NaN   | NaT
 2  |  z   | 970.0 | 2016-04-30 17:00:00
```

when I use executemany from MySQLdb cursors it returns

`Executemany error while connecting to MySQL (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: 'NaT' for column date at row 1")`

So, I tried convert NaT into None with `df.replace({pd.Nat: None}, inplace=True)` now it returns

`Executemany error while connecting to MySQL (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'None' for column 'txn' at row 1")`

Hence, I need to use this `df.replace({pd.NaT: None, np.NaN: None}, inplace=True)` instead but yet still got

`Executemany error while connecting to MySQL (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: 'None' for column 'date' at row 1")`

given the knowledge of [df.replace behavior](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29024)

How can I solved this NaT/None Incorrect datetime value problem

Answer (score 0):

I had been googling for a resolution to the same problem.

```
Executemany error while connecting to MySQL (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: 'NaT' for column date at row 1")
```

What I did after a few hours of research to solve it was converted the datetime to a string type, then ran the replace function.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('str')
df.replace({'NaT': None}, inplace=True)
```

MySQL took my insert statement. Hopefully that works for you as well. Also check your database structure to ensure the 'date' column will allow Null values.